# How to create a OData PUT URL from CPI and Odata Adapter

Tags: odata, sap-cpi

I want to call an OData service with HTTP PUT operation, the OData URL looks like `{baseUrl}/(resourcekey='123')`.

I want to understand how to append the resource key with the base URL from CPI and OData adapter.

Any help would be much appreciated.

I have resource key value saved in the header using groovy script.

I tried creating whole URL with Groovy script but not sure how to update the OData adapter address with new URL.